Eye Spy: Where are the other two (of six) vehicles docked to the ISS in this Maxar image (& what are they?)
I spy Crew Dragon, Starliner, & two Progress (?). Where are the rest?

(Credit: https://www.maxar.com/maxar-intelligence/products/non-earth-imaging)

Upvote for posting the Maxar photo and link. That is way cool.

You might consider adding another answer to Could a spy satellite image another satellite? (I've added probably too many already)

Soyuz MS-25 and Cygnus-20

(NASA)

I prefer the way this page generates ISS occupancy images...
https://historicspacecraft.com/ISS_VV_Diagram.html

You can quickly layout any combination at the station yourself.

The problem with that is that while it can be manipulated to tell you what /might/ be parked and /where/, it doesn't answer the current problem which is "where are things parked /now/?" which is addressed by the dated photo in Steve's answer.

@MarkMorganLloyd - well it does answer the question if you fill in the blanks like geoffc did! It has an option to add a date to the title. It's a pretty nice site although I too was surprised that they don't have a button for "current" that would fill in the current visiting vehicles, but of course that would require constant updating. It's nice for diagramming future configurations, for example here's what things might look like in September if things go according to schedule.
